# C# Razor Pages Selections from check boxes not saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, razor-pages

I have three interlinked classes for SeniorBuddy, Hobby and SeniorBuddyHobbies. Users can must select 3 hobbies and 3 characteristics that apply to them. The form loads displays the checkboxes, but the information does not get saved to the database.

This is my Createcshtml.cs page:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IAPO2.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CreateModel(IAPO2.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public SeniorBuddy SeniorBuddy { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> GenderOptions { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PrefGenderOptions { get; set; }
   


    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        InitializeDropdowns();
        return Page();
    }

    

    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            InitializeDropdowns();
            return Page();
        }

        _context.SeniorBuddies.Add(SeniorBuddy);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
    private void InitializeDropdowns()
    {
        GenderOptions = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SeniorBuddy.Gender))
            .Cast<SeniorBuddy.Gender>()
            .Select(gender => new SelectListItem { Value = gender.ToString(), Text = gender.ToString() })
            .ToList();

        PrefGenderOptions = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SeniorBuddy.PrefGender))
            .Cast<SeniorBuddy.PrefGender>()
            .Select(prefgender => new SelectListItem { Value = prefgender.ToString(), Text = prefgender.ToString() })
            .ToList();
    }
     
    
}
```

Please explain how I can change it to save my checkbox selections.

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the form.